# Move to the directory of a symbolic link

Tags: unix, symbolic-link

On a UNIX machine I in my current directory I create a symbolic link:

```
> ln -s public_html/code/index.html
```

Which creates a file locally named `index.html`. How can `cd` to the directory `public_html/code` from the soft link file?

Comment: What's the reason for this? If you really need to be able to get to the directory holding index.html, perhaps you should create the soft link to that directory, which will let you cd to it.

Comment: @ Harper - I agree, but often times I've forgotten to do just that and simply link to the file instead of a directory. I then get the directory name from an ls and copy and paste that into the command line, clearly not optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `sh`-like environment:

```
cd $(dirname $(readlink -f path/to/link))
```

you can put it in a function:

```
function cdl
{
    cd $(dirname $(readlink -f "$1"))
}
```

Comment: readlink! Awesome, I didn't even know it existed! Accepted this answer over Rich's due to the simplicity, both were great.

Comment: great, under zsh on mac I'm using it without the -f but it seems to work +1

Comment: also for directories I removed the `dirname()` piece.

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
cd_link ()
{
    LINK="$1";
    [ ! -L "$LINK" ] && return;
    DIR=$(readlink "$LINK");
    DIR=${DIR%/*};
    cd $DIR
}
```

This needs to be a function, not a script.  Put in your .bashrc, .kshrc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

one line:

```
cd $(dirname $([ -L $0 ] && readlink -f $0 || echo $0))
```